Write Gaussian with given variance as linear combination of Gaussian densities with other variance?
Let $\mathcal{K}_\sigma$ be the set of Gaussian density functions $f(\cdot;\mu,\sigma)$ with any mean $\mu$ and a given standard deviation $\sigma$.
Now let $t(x):=f(x;\eta,\nu)$ represent the "target" Gaussian density with a given mean $\eta$ and a given standard deviation $\nu$.
How can I expand $t$ in terms of a sum of elements of $\mathcal{K}_\sigma$?
That is, how do I find $a_i$ and $\mu_i$, both in $\mathbb{R}$, such that:
$ t(x) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i f(x;\mu_i, \sigma) $?
Another way of asking the question is: What are the coefficients of the projection of a Gaussian density with location $\eta$ and scale $\nu$ onto the Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Space spanned by Gaussian kernels with scale $\sigma$?

The mixture density that you propose is not a Gaussian density in general, and so no choice of $a_i$'s and $\mu_i$'s can give you the Gaussian density you seek tio match.

@DilipSarwate thanks for your reply. It's not obvious to me that the second part of your sentence follows from the first. Although any finite sum will indeed be non-Gaussian, it's not clear to me that we can't nevertheless get a Gaussian in the limit. Are you aware of a proof of this statement? I am skeptical that it is true because we can do a good job fitting a Gaussian density using a RKHS regression, which seems to suggest that Gaussians of a different width can indeed be represented in this manner.

A finite mixture of Gaussians determines its components.  A comment at the end of my post in that thread places conditions on the $\mu_i$ and $\sigma.$  When all the $\sigma_i$ are equal, the $\mu_i$ cannot be bounded above or below.  If you allow some $a_i$ to be negative (which is allowed in question 2 but not in question 1), there will be solutions.

@whuber good point they're not equivalent; I'll edit the question to focus on question 2.

You might find it helpful to note that these mixtures are the convolution of a countable number of probability atoms (Dirac Deltas) with the Normal distribution of mean $0$ and scale $\sigma.$  It's immediate that there's no solution when $\nu \lt \sigma$ and otherwise you can construct a mixture by approximating a Normal distribution of mean $\eta$ and variance $\nu^2-\sigma^2$ with atoms.

@whuber yes cool thanks that does indeed solve my problem.
